# I do not understand python `print """`

Tags: python

I am trying to create a HTML form from a Python CGI script.

```
script_name=os.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', '')

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
message = form.getvalue("message", "(no message)")

print """

  <p>Previous message: %s</p>

  <p>form

  <form method="post" action="%s">
    <p>message: <input type="text" name="message"/></p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
""" % cgi.escape(message), script_name
```

The above of course does not work.  I was under the false impression that 
whole `print """ blah blah %s ...""" % string_var` worked like C's `printf` function.
So what am I suppose to be doing here?

I get this error message in my browser:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py", line 45, in <module>
    """ % cgi.escape(message), script_name
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: What actually happens? Do you get an error message? If so, can you show it to us?

Comment: Wrap the formatting arguments in parentheses :)

Comment: Without the parentheses, Python thinks you're trying to print two things: a string with a single formatting argument, and a second variable.

Comment: @mhlester has the answer. You should put it as a real answer!

Comment: Nah, I'll let someone with lower rep take a freebie

Comment: Thanks All! changed to `""" % (cgi.escape(message), script_name)` now it works :)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has pointed out that this error has nothing to do with the `print` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the format arguments in parenthesis.

```
print """ %s %s
do re me fa so la ti do
""" % (arg1(arg), arg2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print 'blah' % x, y
```

isn't interpreted as

```
print 'blah' % (x, y)
```

but rather as

```
print ('blah' % x), y
```

Put parentheses around `cgi.escape(message), script_name` to pass a tuple as second argument to `%`. Incidentally, this is one of the reasons you might want to prefer the [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method over `%`.

Answer (score 2):

When your code executes, the first thing that happens is it evaluates the expression

```
long_string % cgi.escape(message)
```

Because there are two keys in the long string but only one value on the other side of the `%` operator, this is failing with the `TypeError` you see.

The solution is to wrap both values in a parentheses, so the second operand is interpreted as a tuple:

```
long_string % (cgi.escape(message), script_name)
```

Comment: A better solution is to use the new `.format` method.  This error would never have occurred if using that.

Comment: [Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)